# getElementsByTagName returns null value (but works weirdly fine in debugging mode)

Tags: javascript

This code is taking in an xml file and parse it and output as a table. Here's a piece of code(Firefox oriented):

```
function viewXML(inputForm) {
        var URL=inputForm.URL.value;    //input XML URL

        // create document and load URL     
        var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","doc",null);
        xmlDoc.load(URL);

        xmlDoc.onload = generateHTML(xmlDoc);
        hWin = window.open("","sth", "height=800,width=600");
        hWin.document.write(html_text);
        hWin.document.close();
    }
```

viewXML is an onClick function of a button. Now a piece of code in `generateHTML()`:

```
function generateHTML(xmlDoc) {
    ...
    caption=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).firstChild.nodeValue;  //<1>
    html_text += "<caption align='left'><h1>" + caption + "</h1></caption>";
    ...
}
```

A piece of XML file:

```
<catalog>
    <title>Airbus_Aircraft_Families</title>
    <aircraft>
        <Airbus>A380</Airbus>
        <Aircraft>A380</Aircraft>
        <seats>555</seats>
        <Range>15000km</Range>
        <Wingspan>78.8m</Wingspan>
        <Height>24.1m</Height>
    </aircraft>
</catalog>
```

**Problem:**
This code works fine when I was running it in debug mode step-by-step-ly in Firebug. BUT if there's no breakpoints set up, when the program hits line <1>, there will show an error saying that:
**xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0) is null** , which is apparently not true.

And **interestingly**, when I tried adding a line

```
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").length)
```

before the <1> line, it will pop up a window shows 0, but after I click "OK", the CORRECT title(from XML) will show up in the new window! As that in step-by-step mode.

**Things I tried:**

1, changing `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0)` to `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]`

Didn't work, debugger told me "xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0] is undefined"

2, Removed all the whitespaces within or between tags in XML file, didn't help.

Comment: It seems taking some time to load the xml and make it as a html element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably due to your document being loaded asynchronously. You can check [document.async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.async) property here. I think if you set this property to false, your code will work.

```
// create document and load URL
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","doc",null);
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.onload = generateHTML(xmlDoc);
xmlDoc.load(URL);
```

Note that I moved the line attaching an event handler to load event before the call to load function.